# How to size multiple canvases in wx.Notebook, issue with float sizes and overlap (WxPython, Matplotlib)

Tags: canvas, matplotlib, wxpython, figure, wxnotebook

I am trying to make a wx.Notebook with a FigureCanvas on each page and unique figures/axes in those canvases.  The problem is that if the figure size (by fig.set_size_inches) is a float to 2 or more decimal places the **figures on different pages will overlap each other slightly**.  I can't for the life of me understand why this is happening and how to fix it.

To see the overlap problem, you have to change to tab 2 and then back to tab 1 and the overlap appears at the bottom of the first graph.

[Picture of what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOTij.png)

```
import wx

# Import Matplotlib
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas

class MyFrame ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):

        # FORM BUILDER OUTPUT
        #########################
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 600,500 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer9 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_notebook2 = wx.Notebook( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_panel5 = wx.Panel( self.m_notebook2, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        bSizer10 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_panel5.SetSizer( bSizer10 )
        self.m_panel5.Layout()
        bSizer10.Fit( self.m_panel5 )
        self.m_notebook2.AddPage( self.m_panel5, u"Page1", False )
        self.m_panel6 = wx.Panel( self.m_notebook2, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        bSizer11 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_panel6.SetSizer( bSizer11 )
        self.m_panel6.Layout()
        bSizer11.Fit( self.m_panel6 )
        self.m_notebook2.AddPage( self.m_panel6, u"Page2", False )

        bSizer9.Add( self.m_notebook2, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.SetSizer( bSizer9 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        #########################

        graph1 = self.create_graph( self.m_panel5, size=(3, 2.255252) )
        graph2 = self.create_graph( self.m_panel6, size=(5.5556, 3.5) )

        ####################

    def create_canvas( self, panel, size ):
        fig = Figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.set_xlim([0,10])
        ax.set_ylim([0,100])
        ax.axis('off')

        fig.set_size_inches( size )  # If this is a float to 3 decimals is causes problems

        canvas = FigureCanvas(panel, -1, fig)
        sizer = panel.GetSizer()
        sizer.Add(canvas)
        return(canvas)

    def create_graph( self, panel, size ):
        canvas = self.create_canvas(panel,size)
        ax = canvas.figure.axes[0]
        xdata = range(1,10)
        ydata = [x*x for x in xdata]
        ax.scatter( xdata, ydata )
        ax.bar( xdata, [100]*9, 0.5, 0, color='red' )
        ax.plot()
        return(ax)


class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        main = MyFrame(None)
        main.Show()
        return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()

print('Done')
```

Comment: I don't see this behavior on Xubuntu. What OS and wxPython version are you using?

Comment: Ah should've mentioned that.  Windows 7 with wxPython 2.8 (['2.8-msw-unicode'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have tried the code on Windows (wxPython 2.9.5.1/mpl 1.3.1) and got the same result (red markings on the bottom of the first plot).

I would tackle the problem however differently and specify the size of the plot not in matplotlib, but in wxPython.

When changing the code as follows:

```
def __init__( self, parent ):
    ...
    graph2 = self.create_graph(#...
    self.Layout() # put this at the end

def create_canvas( self, panel, size ): # size can be omitted
    fig = Figure(dpi=96) # specify the dpi instead of the size
    ...
    # comment this out
    # fig.set_size_inches( size )
```

everything is drawn properly and the sizing makes more sense.

EDIT: The question arose how to have a fixed aspect ratio for the mpl canvas without specifically specifying the size in inches. You can use the `wx.SHAPED` flag instead of `wx.EXPAND` when adding to the sizer and write

```
    bSizer9.Add( self.m_notebook2, 1, wx.SHAPED |wx.ALL, 5 )
```

which will keep the aspect ratio as drawn in `__init__`.

Comment: Aha thank you! I like this solution. I haven't worked with dpi before, is there a way then with wxpython that I can control the aspect ratio of the figure?  It's important to have the height/width ratio as a certain value which is why I was messing with floats in set_size_inches before.

Comment: Interesting question, see edit above. Although I did not get the "accept", I still learned something new from this question.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to call the page's Layout() method whenever you switch between pages. Here's an example that worked for me on Windows 7 with wxPython 3 and Python 2.7:

```
import wx

# Import Matplotlib
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas

class MyFrame ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):

        # FORM BUILDER OUTPUT
        #########################
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 600,500 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer9 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_notebook2 = wx.Notebook( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_notebook2.Bind(wx.EVT_NOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGED, self.onPageChanged)
        self.m_panel5 = wx.Panel( self.m_notebook2, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        bSizer10 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_panel5.SetSizer( bSizer10 )
        self.m_panel5.Layout()
        bSizer10.Fit( self.m_panel5 )
        self.m_notebook2.AddPage( self.m_panel5, u"Page1", False )
        self.m_panel6 = wx.Panel( self.m_notebook2, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        bSizer11 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_panel6.SetSizer( bSizer11 )
        self.m_panel6.Layout()
        bSizer11.Fit( self.m_panel6 )
        self.m_notebook2.AddPage( self.m_panel6, u"Page2", False )

        bSizer9.Add( self.m_notebook2, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.SetSizer( bSizer9 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        #########################

        graph1 = self.create_graph( self.m_panel5, size=(3, 2.255252) )
        graph2 = self.create_graph( self.m_panel6, size=(5.5556, 3.5) )

        ####################

    def create_canvas( self, panel, size ):
        fig = Figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.set_xlim([0,10])
        ax.set_ylim([0,100])
        ax.axis('off')

        fig.set_size_inches( size )  # If this is a float to 3 decimals is causes problems

        canvas = FigureCanvas(panel, -1, fig)
        sizer = panel.GetSizer()
        sizer.Add(canvas)
        return(canvas)

    def create_graph( self, panel, size ):
        canvas = self.create_canvas(panel,size)
        ax = canvas.figure.axes[0]
        xdata = range(1,10)
        ydata = [x*x for x in xdata]
        ax.scatter( xdata, ydata )
        ax.bar( xdata, [100]*9, 0.5, 0, color='red' )
        ax.plot()
        return(ax)

    def onPageChanged(self, event):
        self.m_panel5.Layout()
        self.m_panel6.Layout()


class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        main = MyFrame(None)
        main.Show()
        return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: When I use EVT_NOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGED, the sizes of the two graphs aren't different (there's no change from one tab to another.  Do  you see this as well? I also tried EVT_NOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGING, which makes the sizes different but then the overlap problems remains.

Comment: No, I don't. The graphs are still different sizes but the overlap isn't there. Maybe it could be a difference between wx 2.8 and wx 3.0?

Comment: Upgraded to 3.0 and everything works smoothly.  Thank you very much!  This has been frustrating me to no end.  There might be some ends to fix up now that I'm using 3.0 but I doubt it will be nearly as confusing as this has been...